# Removing id from a url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to remove id from the url. below are one of the url's

```
http://example.com/post-1-postname.html
```

Rewrite rule in the .htaccess file is

```
RewriteRule post-([0-9]+)-(.*)\.html$ post.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

and this script is using $_GET and use it to display the post

```
$id = $mysqli->escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

my question how can i remove the id from the url and still make it work with the $_GET request to display the post. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: No that can't be done. If `id` is gone from request then `GET` will also not get it. Look at above Stackoverlow URL, there is a reason why `/29556110/` is there in URL.

Comment: You can get ID from new URLs for SQL query eg. using regexp. Or use URL `example.com/post/1/postname/`.

Comment: Maybe hashing base64 or some custome home made fuction if you realy don't want to be seen your DB id by public

Answer (score 2):

You need *some* identifying information in the URL to know what resource is being requested. You can't "hide" the id, it's either there or it isn't. If you don't want a *numeric* id in the URL, then you need to create textual ids. I.e., if all your posts have a title, make a slug out of it ("Hello World!" → "hello_world"), save that in your database, **ensure it's unique**, and then create your URL: http://example.com/posts/hello_world. Your id `1` has been replaced by the id `hello_world`.

Comment: good point. I will try it but i was hoping for more or .htaccess solution.

Comment: It's not magic. The URL is the identifier. If the information you need to identify the post isn't in the URL, then it can't be anywhere else.